# log-in / log-out / log-in SDK mobile push: duplicated contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android, push-notification, logout

Im dealing with the following use case and I would like to know what does in happens in the All contacts table. I have Delay registration: false

1. User X install the App without doing the log-in
2. User X makes log-in
3. User X makes log-out
4. User X makes log-in

---

I would like to know if what I think happens in the All contact is correct:

1. A record A is created with a random Contact Key and a specific
   device ID
2. The device ID an all the attributes are associated to the known
   Contact Key (record B). The record A does not have anymore associated
   data and can't be used for contact purposes
3. The devide ID is not anymore associated to the record B and a
   new record (record C) with that Devide ID is created
4. The device ID an all the attributes are associated to the known
   Contact Key (record B). The record C does not have anymore associated
   data and can't be used for contact purposes

Is that correct?

Thank you,
Sofia